# Smoother JQuery width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a menu where the hovered block is getting bigger, while the siblings are offering their space for this size increase. All blocks together are taking up the whole window width.

I successfully accomplished that using some basic Jquery, but the result is a bit clunky.
The rightmost div suffers from all the calculations and rounding :

```
var width = $(window).width() - 44;
var blockwidth = width/12;
var blockwidthLarge = blockwidth+154;
var blockwidthSmall = blockwidth-14;
$('.headerblock').css('width',blockwidth+'px').hover(function()
   {
      $(this).siblings().stop(false,false).animate({width: blockwidthSmall},300);
      $(this).stop(false,false).animate({width: blockwidthLarge},300);

   },function()
   {
       $(this).siblings().stop(false,false).animate({width: blockwidth},300);
      $(this).stop(false,false).animate({width: blockwidth},300);

   });
```

This is a working jsfiddle (I would recommend to resize the preview frame to something larger to increase the effect's visibility):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QA72Q/)

How can I improve this to have the boxes appear stable? Maybe this has already been developed?
The website should be IE8+ compatible, so I cannot use fancy css rules.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to accomplish something like Apple's 30 years campaign, you could try to emulate them and stack the elements each on top of each other and change their position rather than width.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin called [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) by [Brian Cherne](http://cherne.net) that might solve your issue.

Basically, what it does is only firing the hover event when it thinks that the user actually meant to hover. It's a *little* less fluid than the original, but it works big time and looks fancy.

Here's a fiddle with the plugin added under "External Resources" and the

```
$('.headerblock').hover(function() {
```

changed to ".hoverIntent"

http://jsfiddle.net/Matze/c4uyR/1/

```
var width = $(window).width() - 44;
var blockwidth = Math.round(width / 12);
var blockwidthLarge = blockwidth + 154;
var blockwidthSmall = blockwidth - 14;
$('.headerblock').css('width', blockwidth + 'px').hoverIntent(function ()
{
    $(this).siblings().stop(false, false).animate({
        width: blockwidthSmall
    }, 300);
    $(this).stop(false, false).animate({
        width: blockwidthLarge
    }, 300);

}, function () {
    $(this).siblings().stop(false, false).animate({
        width: blockwidth
    }, 300);
    $(this).stop(false, false).animate({
        width: blockwidth
    }, 300);

});
```